# SpringJPAData: data not refreshed after update

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am updating a field in LOGIN object by using @Query in UserRepository, then imminently do a find to select the login object, the data is not refreshed. I do see the updated record in the database. If I bounce my tomcat server, go to the page on my browser, i will see the refreshed data. 
As shown below, I updated LOGIN.enabled to 1 (updateUserLoginEnableByUuid()) then call findByLoginLoginEmail(), the LOGIN.enable is still showing as 0.
It seems like the old record is still cached somewhere, what am I missing?

in UserConroller.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/enableUser/{userUuid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String enableUser(Model aaModel, @PathVariable("userUuid") String userUuid, Principal aaPrincipal, SessionStatus aaStatus) {

    this.caService.updateUserLoginEnableByUuid(userUuid, (byte) 1);

    aaStatus.setComplete();

    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

in userRepository.java,

```
    @Modifying // Indicates a method should be regarded as modifying query.
    @Query("update Login l SET l.enabled = :enabled WHERE l.user.uuid = :uuid")
    int updateUserLoginEnableByUuid(@Param("uuid") String uuid, @Param("enabled") byte enabled);

User findByLoginLoginEmail(String loginEmail);
```

Comment: the data is not refreshed - where is it not refreshed?

Comment: I updated LOGIN.enabled to 1 (updateUserLoginEnableByUuid()) then call findByLoginLoginEmail(), the LOGIN.enable is still showing as 0.

Comment: so something is doing a GET on the enableuser, and then after the redirect, persumably when the user is attempting to login, the login fails?  If you turn on show SQL, when is the SQL sent?  and when is the data committed?

Answer (score 2):

when you're doing DML or SQL queries, which completely bypass the entity manager cache (as in your example). In this case, the state held by the cache doesn't reflect what is in the database because of the queries

To achieve update you need to clear entitymanager cache after you execute the update query to reflect those changes in database.

You can access entitymanager as `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;` and then execute `em.clear();` after update query.